# CMake: how to declare a file being a dependency on CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake

I have a custom additional build definition information provided by some external files, which should be treated by CMake similar way as just an `include()` file, however there's a special macro for parsing the information from this file.

What I need is that CMake recognize these files as part of the build definition, and if it finds them refreshed (just like the CMakeLists.txt file is fresher than the target build files), it causes re-running of the "configure step".

Can there be something like "declaring a file being an include" or "declare a dependency of `CMakeLists.txt` file"?

These "special custom include files" are not generated, they just may be updated by the developer.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. Thanks for finding it.

Comment: Sorry for being to dumb to know how to mark this duplicate.

Comment: You can only set it as duplicate via the `close` flag, if the other question has an upvoted answer.